# Update Sharepoint list view using REST web service

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am developing a plugin using Java for SharePoint 2013, trying to update the list view using SharePoint REST web services, but could not find any way to go.

GetListAndView method fetches the view and field details but dont see anything to update those views.

As a work around , developing the a SharePoint solution in C# and exposing it as web service method to add, update, delete the fields in the view.

Any pointers to achieve using web services would be appreciated.

Using the MSDN help at the [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433%28v=office.15%29.aspx#bk_ViewFieldCollectionAddViewField)

Tried to add/update/remove the fields using the urls as in MSDN
http:///_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists(guid'')/views('')/viewfields/removeviewfield('Jira_x0020_URL')?@target=''

**Getting Error:**

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">There is no app context to execute this request.</m:message>
<m:innererror>
<m:message>There is no app context to execute this request.</m:message>
<m:type>Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:type>
<m:stacktrace>
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAppContextSite..ctor(String siteUrl)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPAppContextSiteServerStub.InvokeConstructor(ClientValueCollection xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeConstructorWithMonitoredScope(ClientValueCollection args, ProxyContext proxyContext)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.GetObjectFromPathRoot(Boolean mainRequestPath, EdmParserNode node, Boolean resourceEndpoint, MethodInformation& methodInfo)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.GetObjectFromPath(Boolean mainRequestPath, String path, String pathForErrorMessage)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.Process()
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest()
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestService.ProcessQuery(Stream inputStream, IList`1 pendingDisposableContainer)
</m:stacktrace>
<m:internalexception>
<m:message>There is no app context to execute this request.</m:message>
<m:type>Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientServiceException</m:type>
<m:stacktrace/>
</m:internalexception>
</m:innererror>
</m:error>
```

**Looking for REST api rather than web http url get/post.**

Comment: Did you get a solution for this error?